# Extjs ownerCt undefined

Tags: extjs

I created a `new` component in my grid's `listeners`: `beforeload`, and when i called `.show()` on it, the debugger showed that `d.ownerCt` is `undefined`. Any suggestions?

Comment: See answer below on why this happens. But what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

`ownerCt` is set automatically by the framework as soon as a component is added to a container. It seems that you're calling `show()` manually indicating that your component is not part of a container hierarchy.

See [`ownerCt`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-property-ownerCt) in the Ext JS documentation (here Ext JS 6 classic, but that concept hasn't changed).

> This Component's owner Container (is set automatically when this
>   Component is added to a Container).
>
> Important. This is not a universal upwards navigation pointer. It
>   indicates the Container which owns and manages this Component if any.
>   There are other similar relationships such as the button which
>   activates a menu, or the menu item which activated a submenu, or the
>   column header which activated the column menu.
>
> These differences are abstracted away by the up method.
>
> Note: to access items within the Container see itemId.